# Filament Group Flat Menu and FancyBox conflict

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fancybox, conflict

I am using filament group flat menu. On click of first anchor, I want to open another page in FancyBox but it doesn't seems to be working. When clicked, the other page gets opened in the same window rather than in the FancyBox. If, I use the same anchor outside the menu div, FancyBox works without any issues. Please help.

*Development environment: ASP.NET 4.0, JQuery v1.7, JQuery UI v1.8.18, FancyBox v1.3.4*

Following is the JQuery code for reference:

```
$('a#aShowLevels').live('mousedown', function() {
    var l_sHref = "./tbl.aspx?iframe?id=" + $("#hftbTID").val();
    $("a#aShowLevels").attr("href", l_sHref);
    $(this).trigger('click');
});

$("a#aShowLevels").fancybox({
    'showIframeLoading': true,
    'enableEscapeButton': true,
    'width': 680,
    'height': 540
});
```

Following is the HTML Code:

```
<a tabindex="0" href="#divMenuOptions" class="fg-button fg-button-icon-right ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="flatMenu"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>Options</a>
<div id="divMenuOptions" class="hidden">
    <ul>
    <li><a id="aShowLevels" href="#" class="iframe" runat="server">Show Bids</a></li>
    <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lkbtnConvertToPO" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/po.aspx">Convert to PO</asp:LinkButton></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: provide anchor click code and .fancybox({ code to display page.

Comment: Following is the anchor click code and fancybox code:  
$('a#aShowLevels').live('mousedown', function() {  
 var l_sHref = "./tbl.aspx?id=" + $("#txtId").val();  
 $("a#aShowLevels").attr("href", l_sHref);  
 $(this).trigger('click');  
});  
  
$("a#aShowLevels").fancybox({  
 'showIframeLoading': true,  
 'enableEscapeButton': true,  
 'width': 680,  
 'height': 540  
});

Comment: edit in your question bro. can't readable.

Comment: see this stackoverflow question [click me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020084/open-html-page-within-fancybox)

Comment: @PriyankPatel .. thank you for comments and let me justify on the one at a time. I tried but I am unable to format my code in the comments box for which I sincerely apologies and on to the fancybox code, well as you may read my question, the fancybox code is   working if I remove the anchor outside the menu div. Plz comment.

Comment: I have found the solution to my problem but due to reputation policy of stackoverflow, I am unable to post it. Will post the same after 6 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which is as follows:

Changed the anchor properties from ...

```
<li><a id="aShowLevels" href="#" class="iframe" runat="server">Show Bids</a></li>
```

to

```
<li><a id="aShowLevels" href="#" runat="server" onclick="var goURL='./tbl.aspx?id=' + $('#hftbTID').val();openFB(goURL)">Show Bids</a></li>
```

Removed the **live** event and fancybox function attached to **a#aShowLevels** element and added the following function:

```
    function openFB(url) {
        $.fancybox({
            'href': url,
            'type': 'iframe',
            'width': '95%',
            'height': '90%'
        });
    }
```

credit goes to @JFK (url: http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/4449cbde5e004365/98735950117f861b)

Comment: Glad to hear that some old posts are still useful :)

Comment: Thank you @JFK but I could not accept my own answer due to the my reputation as per Stackoverflow policies, but now I have done it. Thanks for the brief explanation in your article which helped me solve my issue.