# Use Fancybox in ASP Gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, fancybox

I would like to make use of Fancybox plugin in my ASP.NET website.

*Please note that I am inexperienced programmer*

**BRIEF SUMMARY**

My website has two aspx pages, the first page hold asp:GridView that has asp:HyperLinkField, when clicked a popup windows "should" appear having more details about the clicked row.

**DETAILS**

1)*Default.aspx* holds gridview that has asp:HyperLinkField to pass database fields to URL. Note that i used CssClass to provide Fancybox class *'various'*

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <Columns>
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="kpiName" HeaderText="Name" 
        DataNavigateUrlFields="kpiNo, unit, YTD, kpiName, YEE" 
        DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../Popup/Detail.aspx?
         kpiNo={0}&unit={1}&YTD=  {2}&kpiName={3}&YEE={4}"> 
        <ControlStyle CssClass="various"></ControlStyle>
        </asp:HyperLinkField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="unit" HeaderText="unit" SortExpression="unit" />
        ...
    </Columns>
```

2)*Details.aspx* has asp:DetailView and VB code to get the passed argument using

```
Request.QueryString("urlField")
```

3) Fancybox script

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".various").fancybox({
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 600,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '70%',
            height      : '70%',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none'
        });
    });
```

**What i want to accomplish is to pass the Url Fields to Details.aspx and then show Details.aspx in a popup windows created by Fancybox**

Thank you

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020084/open-html-page-within-fancybox), In your case "<a href="http://www.example?iframe">This goes to iframe</a>" this line will be replaced by <a href="../Popup/Detail.aspx?kpiNo={0}&unit={1}&YTD=  {2}&kpiName={3}&YEE={4}">This goes to iframe</a>

Comment: Just bear in mind that the OP is using fancybox v2.x ... in that case the class should be `class="various fancybox.iframe"` if iframe is what he needs.