# Failed to load external HTML file via Fancybox…

Tags: fancybox

I followed the suggestion here [Open html page within fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020084/open-html-page-within-fancybox), and read up the examples in fancybox.net, and managed to get it half done.

What's been successful so far:
* pointing the cursor on the icon shows the full, correct URL
* for testing, the external HTML page shows "Hi" and contains nothing else
* clicking on the icon brings up the fancybox

What's not working:
* the content of the fancybox reads "The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later."

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
< div id="container" style="bottom: 0px; left: 2px; position: fixed; width:40px; z-index: 999999;">
    <br>
    < a id="single_1" href="helpme.html">
        <img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/helpme.png"/>
    </a>
    <br>
< /div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    $('#single_1').fancybox({
        helpers: {
            title : {
                type : 'float'
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with 5 mins, with colorbox.